# How to efficiently loop through two data frames for comparing columns and filling data

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, time-complexity

I have the following piece of code to iterate through two data frames.

```
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    for j, innerrow in df2.iterrows():
        if row["df1_id"] == innerrow["df2_id"]:
            df1.at[i,"count_col_df1"] = innerrow["count_col_df2"]
```

Here, **the comparison of ID's column is done to fill the data of one column in df1 from df2.**
Since there are 10,000+ records in each data frame, it is taking hours to complete.
Any suggestions for efficient ways to compile the code would be welcomed.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly this should help you. `eq()` is returning True or False by checking the values if whether equals.

```
df2.loc[df1['df1_id'].eq(df2['df2_id']), 'count_col_df2'] = df1['count_col_df1']
```